# How to detect whether any points in the coastline is facing to the open sea or not?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a set of Mangrove stands polygon derived from remotely sensed data and the coastline data (Line). I am going to detect any point in the boundary of mangrove polygon is located in the outer side of the coastline and exposed to the open sea?

Can anyone suggested me how can i do it in ARCGIS?

Comment: some visual example would be helpful to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are attempting to classify mangroves as per the **fringe**, riverine, basin standard definition.

Polygons cannot really face something. What you are asking appears to be is the stand located within "sea" and this is very difficult to answer as once the stand exists it technically becomes land so only the outer edge of the stand (which is resolution as opposed to location based) is actually adjacent to sea. I would suggest to get the highest detail coastline of your area and just assign the stand as either the landward side or seaward side of the coastline.

To do this I usually just have the coastline integrated into a country / region / land polygon and merely run a inside / outside poly test on the other polygon. A simple [intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000z000000) will tell you if any part is inside and what does not is outside. A simple [union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000) will give you all possible geometries and then you can just [attribute select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000) those without the land ID to get outside.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clearly asked...
Let's imagine a perpendicular line is drawn from any points from the coastline, are there any method to check whether this perpendicular line will touch the coastline again. If yes, i can assume this point is located in the inner side and being protested from the sea wave.